# C++ enum evaluates to unexpected value

Tags: c++, arrays, enums

I have an enum defined as below so expect it to be returning values between 0-6

```
enum blocks
{ none = 0, red, green, blue, yellow, white, black };

Grid<blocks> gameGrid; // initialised to none
```

I am trying to use the enum as an offset into an array containing the colours for the blocks. However `gameGrid[y][x]` is returning a number outside of the range above, causing a segmentation fault.

```
fixedColor = colourArray[gameGrid[y][x]];
```

I have checked y and x are within range (0-19), gdb reports:

> ```
> (gdb) print y
> $1 = 19
> (gdb) print x
> $2 = 5
> (gdb) print gameGrid[y][x]
> $3 = (blocks &) @0x8201dc4: 136172580
> ```

Below is the definition of the Grid:

```
template <typename T>
class Grid
{
    std::deque<Row<T> > rows;
    T defaultValue;

public:
    const unsigned width, height;

    Grid(unsigned inWidth, unsigned inHeight, T inValue) : defaultValue(inValue), width(inWidth), height(inHeight)
    {
        Row<T> r(width, inValue);  
        for (unsigned i = height; i; --i)        
            rows.push_back(r);
    }    

    Row<T>& operator[](unsigned arg) { return rows[arg]; }
```

.....

As for Row:

```
template <typename T>
class Row
{
public:
    std::vector<T> elements;
    Row(unsigned inWidth, T inValue) : elements(inWidth, inValue) {};
    T& operator[](unsigned arg) { return elements[arg]; }
```

....

And I call:

```
Game::Game(App& inApp) : theApp(inApp), bgColour(sf::Color::Black), gridWidth(10), gridHeight(20), gameGrid(gridWidth, gridHeight, blocks::none),
```

.....

I am curious as to how a value of the gameGrid of blocks type could evaluate to 136172580.
Any thoughts on what I am missing would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What is Grid? If its has an array internally, how does it know how much space to allocate based on the enum passed to it as a template argument?

Comment: Can we see the constructor of the `Grid` class, or where you should initialize the array?

Comment: What happens with `{ none = 0, red = 1, green = 2, blue = 3, yellow = 4, white = 5, black = 6 };`?

Comment: What is Grid? What is x? What is y? what do the involved operator[] return? At least those things need to be known to get to an opinion of what the code could be doing. Better would be you created a selfcontained compiling single-translation-unit testcase.

Comment: @AlessandroPezzato That's guaranteed by all C and C++ standards.

Comment: Having a value for an enum outside the enum's valid range does not result in segmentation faults. Segmentation faults are caused by trying to access a memory location you do not have permission to access.

Comment: Thank you for all your responses, I have included the relevant Row and Grid definitions.

Comment: @EricFinn I should clarify, I did not mean to imply the enum was causing the segfault, rather the larger offset was, as you describe.

Comment: Update: Issue persists, I have printed out the contents of the Grid  and it is completely initialised after ctor is called.

Answer (score 1):

This feels a lot like an uninitialised variable problem - you haven't initialised your enums in the grid in all cases. As you're using gdb you are probably on a Linux platform. Have you tried running your exe through [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)? It'll tell you about such things...

Comment: ==4026== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==4026==    at 0x804A683: gdf::Game::display() (Game.cpp:116)

Answer (score 0):

My psychic debugging powers tell me that your `gameGrid` is implemented in terms of a vector of vectors (or similar), and that the extent of one of the vectors isn't large enough (did you forget to call `push_back` or `resize`?): you're running off the end of the space with your chosen `x` and `y`. Once you're out of the range of your space all bets are off as to the value of the memory you read.

From your question it sounds like you most likely come from a language other than C or C++. In C++, while it gives you significant tools to help write correct code, there is a wide variety of incorrect code that will still compile just fine. The compiler assumes that you know what you're doing and have allocated the proper amount of memory. If you write incorrect code C++ lets you read from pretty much arbitrary memory, so it's not at all surprising that you could get a seemingly invalid/garbage value for your enumerated type.

EDIT: A new idea that comes to mind here. If, within the `sf::Style::Fullscreen Game::Game` class your `gameGrid` member is declared before the width and height members, it will be initialized first, with garbage values. The order you list them in the constructor is irrelevant to the order they actually get initialized. g++ even has a warning for this.

Comment: Computer graphics oftentimes use arrays that are in column major order.

Comment: Hi Mark, you are right, I am new at C++.I have posted the code above, I am initialising with push_back

Comment: Good thinking but the grids are independent and g++ is not warning me about the order of initialisation (and -Wall is on).